# How can I allocate more space to a numeric

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

Here is the XAML code that I created:

```xml
<ViewCell>
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="ABC" />
      <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

When I run the code the data entry area for the window is only wide enough to show one digit. Is there a way I can expand this so it will allow me to enter three digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a WidthRequest value, and also try changing the HorizontalOptions

```xml
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```